# Webpack 2 CommonsChunkPlugin Vendor Bundle

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Webpack 2 question / clarification related to `CommonsChunkPlugin`.

```
{
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.ts',
        vendor: ['some-third-party-lib', 'another-third-party-lib']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: Infinity
        })  ]
}
```

As I understand it, `CommonsChunkPlugin` breaks out common code that is shared between entry points into a separate bundle. In the above snippet, it would be saying "give me all shared code between my entry points 'app' and 'vendor'" and put them in the `vendor` chunk / file. Since `vendor` is both an entry point and a shared chunk, the result is that all my 3rd party libs end up in the 1 file (`vendor.js`). Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, correct! Please refer to [Webpack guides](https://webpack.js.org/guides/) for better understanding.

Comment: Yeah the webpack guides helped me get to this configuration, but was still lacking a little connecting the dots IMO. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the `minChunks` option to `CommonsChunkPlugin` configures the following:

> The minimum number of chunks which need to contain a module before it's moved into the commons chunk.
>
> Passing `Infinity` just creates the commons chunk, but moves no modules into it.

src: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#options

In your example, the `CommonsChunkPlugin` would only pull out the chunks specified in the `vendor` entry point, and it would not automatically detect other shared chunks. If the `minChunks` option were removed, the plugin would automatically include chunks referenced by all entry points. In this case, you only have two entry points, so it wouldn't make a difference.